# Custom query results generate code

Tags: html, sql, wordpress, frontend

Simple question. I have the following custom query. How do I make it generate a html list of the array via "echo?"

```
$q_result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->terms}.name FROM {$wpdb->terms}
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = {$wpdb->terms}.term_id
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'series' AND {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id IN (
        SELECT object_id FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships}
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'media_type' AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = '16'
        ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order DESC
        ) ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order ASC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the array with a `foreach` -

```
foreach( $q_result as $result ){
   echo "<a href='/series/".$result."/>".$result."</a>";
}
```

If you want it to display HTML as well, you will have to echo the proper HTML tags. The above will sort of work for links to the term - the format is TAXONOMY/TERM_SLUG however you are only returning the name, you need to get the name and the slug using `get_results()` to do it properly.

Reformatted example using table aliases, returning the term and slug:

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT DISTINCT t.name, t.slug 
    FROM {$wpdb->terms} t
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt 
        ON tt.term_id = t.term_id and tt.taxonomy = 'series'
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr 
        ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE tr.object_id IN (
        SELECT object_id 
        FROM {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr2
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt2 
            ON tt2.term_taxonomy_id = tr2.term_taxonomy_id AND tt2.taxonomy = 'media_type' AND tt2.term_id = '16'
        ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order DESC
    ) 
    ORDER BY {$wpdb->terms}.term_order ASC
SQL;

$terms = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
for ( $terms as $term ){
    echo "<a href='/series/{$term->slug}/'>{$term->name}</a><br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks you! How would I echo the permalinks?

Comment: Assuming the permalinks for the term... see my edit, but it won't really work because you are getting the name and not the slug.

Comment: What do I need to do to grab both the name and the slug?

Comment: I added an example, untested, but it should be a start. Back to work for me.